# How do I filter @Query with bound item

Tags: swift-data, xcode15

I have a few that is passed an item of type FamilyMember. Available in the view is a list of Chores. A chore has a member assigned to it. I want to filter the chores to the passed family member.

2 Structures and view code:

```swift
@Model
class Chore: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var frequency: ChoreFrequency
    var assignedTo: FamilyMember
    var isComplete: Bool
    var dueDate: Date

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String = "", frequency: ChoreFrequency = .daily, assignedTo: FamilyMember = FamilyMember(), isComplete: Bool = false, dueDate: Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.assignedTo = assignedTo
        self.isComplete = isComplete
        self.dueDate = dueDate
    }
}


@Model
class FamilyMember: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String { name }
    var name: String

    init(name: String = "Unassigned") {
        self.name = name
    }
}

// Hashable extension 




struct MemberView: View {
    @Bindable var member: FamilyMember
    @Query private var chores: [Chore]

    init(member: FamilyMember) {
        self.member = member
        let predicate = #Predicate<Chore> {
            $0.assignedTo == member  // <— Error occurs here!
        }

        _chores = Query(filter: predicate, sort: \.dueDate)
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

It's when creating the predicate that I'm running to an error of value conversion.
`Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Chore>, FamilyMember>, PredicateExpressions.Value<FamilyMember>>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like another relationship related bug to me.